# Escape Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, command, salesforce, escaping, pipeline

I have a problem with an escape in Azure Pipeline.

This is the line with I'm having the problem:

```
  cmd="sfdx force:org:create --targetdevhubusername DevHub --wait 10 --durationdays 1 --definitionfile ${{ parameters.scratchOrgFile }} orgName='My Personal Package/my_branch' --setdefaultusername --setalias BuildOrg --json" && (echo $cmd >&2)
```

The argument orgName has the value "My Personal Package/my_branch".

This command is between "" and I try to write the argument for orgName between:

'My Personal Package/my_branch'

"My Personal Package/my_branch"

'My Personal Package/my_branch'

"My Personal Package/my_branch"

^"My Personal Package/my_branch^"

I tried to change the quotation marks for full command to signle '', but still not working.

Sometimes I received this error, note that Personal is the second word in my argument:

```
  Error in the following argument
```

Personal
Set varargs with this format: key=value or key="value with spaces"

Some times I received this other:

```
  line 3: Personal: command not found
```

The orgName argument is really a variable that has spaces and a /, I've discarded a problem with the variable writing a value instead using the variable

The full command without cmd="...", only the sfdx command (with orgName="My Personal Package/my_branch") works perfect in my local, so I guess that is a problem with the quotation marks.

Thanks

Comment: What does the task look like with which you are running this command? Why do you need cmd="" ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. The problem was a copy paste from another pipeline and I use the format cmd="".
I simply remove the cmd="" and write the command. It works now.
Thanks